# Is this the right way of deleting the tail from the linked list in c#

Tags: c#

Is this the right way of deleting the tail from the linked list in c# by simply setting the pointer to null.How do I actually free up the node. Do I need to implement Idispose

```
public void DeleteTail()
    {
        if (head == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("you cannot delete from an empty list.");
        }
        SingleLinkedListNode<T> current = head;

        while (current.Next.Next != null)
        {
            current = current.Next;
        }

        //delete the node
        current.Next = null;
    }

//Appends a node to the linked list
public  SingleLinkedListNode<T> AppendNode(T value)
    {
        SingleLinkedListNode<T> newNode = new SingleLinkedListNode<T>(value, null);
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            SingleLinkedListNode<T> current = head;

            while (current.Next != null)
            {
                current = current.Next;
            }
            current.Next = newNode;
        }


        return newNode;
    }
```

Comment: Something to consider in your code.  What happens in your `DeleteTail()` method if you have only 1 item in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything apart from setting the reference to `null`. The garbage collector will not find any references to the object, so it knows that it is not a live object and will release the memory.

You only need to implement `IDisposable` if you hold *unmanaged* resources (e.g. a database connection or file handle). Then you should explicitly call `Dispose` on your node when you no longer need it, in order to release the resources it holds as soon as possible.

---

You should also note that you have an error in your program. If your list contains only one element, this line will throw a `NullReferenceException`:

```
while (current.Next.Next != null)
```

You need to also check `head.Next == null`.

Comment: Actually How would I delete if I have a single node.

Comment: @leaner a tip ,if you would Clear a LinkedList than Null the head ,same thing as Mark Byers is sugesting so you can make a method which clears the List and use that also in this case